# GetValue on static field inside nested classes

Tags: c#, static, field

I have the following class declared. I need to retreive the class structure and the static values without instanciate it.

```
public class MyClass()
{
    public static string field = "Value";

    public class nestedClass()
    {
        public static string nestedField = "NestedValue";
    }
}
```

I've successfuly used GetFields and GetNestedType to recover the class structure and GetValue(null) works fine on field, but not on nestedField.
Let me sample:

```
var fi = typeof(MyClass).GetField("field", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var nt = typeof(MyClass).GetNestedType("nestedClass", BindingFlags.Public);
var nfi = nt.GetField("nestedField", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
// All the above references are detected correctly
var value = fi.GetValue(null); // until here everything works fine. value == "Value"
var nestedValue = nfi.GetValue(null); // this one does not work!!
```

Anyone knows why the last line does not work and how to work around?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a short but *complete* piece of code. Currently you don't have a nested class - you have a *method* called `nestedClass`. If you can provide us something we can cut, paste and run to experiment with, that will help a lot.

Comment: It would be worth knowing what exception you get. It can be code security issue for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well it all seems to work fine to me and after the last line I get the "NestedValue" string. Tried on .net frameworks 3.5 , 4 and 4.5, everything works (VS2012 Pro). ReSharper states though, that fi, and nfi might be a possible null reference.

> public class MyClass()
>   {

Don't put "()" at the end of your class, that code is still experimental, and it's redundant unless you actually want to use the experimental code, then you'd have to provide some arguments to the constructor.